# WPF disposing of view and viewmodel correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've written an Outlook add-in (OL2010). It has a menu on the ribbon bar with various icons that open new windows that do stuff (hope that's not too in-depth ;)).  An example of one of the icon `Click` handlers is below.

```
public void OnViewMyTracksClick(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
    try {
    MyTracksViewModel viewModel = new MyTracksViewModel();
    MyTracksView view = new MyTracksView();
    view.DataContext = viewModel;
    view.Show();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error("xxxxx", "Error on button click: " + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.InnerException);
    }
}
```

In Outlook, if I click the button to open this view, I see the memory usage of `Outlook.exe` increase by 10mb (the window and it's accompanying data). When I close the view, none of that memory is reclaimed. If I click the button again, another 10mb is added, and again, none is released when I close the view.

I thought that this is because I'm creating a new viewmodel everytime, so I added some code to check if it was already instantiated (the view and viewmodel are now registered at the class level, rather that within the method, so that I don't create a new one each time) - `_allTracksVM` is an instantiation of `AllTracksViewModel`. `_allTracksV` is the view.

```
public void OnViewAllTracksClick(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
    try {
        if (_allTracksVM == null)
        {
            _allTracksVM = new AllTracksViewModel();

        }
        _allTracksV = new AllTracksView();
        _allTracksV.DataContext = _allTracksVM;
        _allTracksV.Show();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error("xxxxx", "Error on button click: " + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.InnerException);
    }
}
```

This didn't seem to make any difference. I then added an `EventHandler` that would fire when the view was closed:

```
_allTracksV.Closing += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.view_RequestClose);
```

And this set both the objects to null (you can probably tell i'm grabbing at straws at this point):

```
void view_RequestClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _allTracksVM = null;
    _allTracksV = null;
}
```

The memory remains allocated. How can I dispose of the objects correctly (or perhaps I should be instantiating them differently), so that they don't consume another chunk of memory each time they are opened?

Thanks

Mick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the VM for Null was a good idea but by setting it to null in the close handler, it is rendered useless :)
You could try to make the view a field in the containing class rather than a local variable. That way you don't need to create a new view each time.

As for the memory usage, it seems to me that you're doing it right. Since the GC only collects when necessary, it will take some time until the memoryusage declines.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Got rid of the null thing in the close handler.  I would've hoped that closing the view would also dispose of it (at least eventually), but it doesn't seemt to.  My Outlook initially runs at about 100mb.  I can keep opening and closing the window until Outlook is using in excess of 500mb.  There's definitely only one instance of the view model now, so my uneducated guess is that the views are hanging around consuming memory.  Not sure how often garbage collection should take place, but 2 hours made no difference.

Comment: Did you try to make the view itself a field? So that you don't have to create a new view each time, but just show and hide it?

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing and it seems to have made a reasonable amount of difference.  Memory still goes up, but considerably slower, and now seems to only happen with one view (that's embedded in an element host that get shown in the preview window).  There's probably a temorary result set that's hanging around.  Thanks for the suggestion.